# Как вывести диапазон значений из двумерного массива

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

есть масиив

```
$arr3 = array(
  array( "01.05", "07.05" ),
  array( "01.06", "07.06" )
);
```

Необходимо вывести диапазон дат с первого и со второго масиива что бы получилось так: 01.05 , 02.05, 03.05 .... 01.06, 02.06 и.т.д

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, можно ли в решении задачи использовать слияние массива из одного в другой. Это потребует дополнительную память, для хранения нового одномерного массива. После этого потребуется только правильно отсортировать массив.